# How to use angular animation in child component

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I have an animation defined in app component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  animations: [
    trigger('fade', [
      state('void', style({
        opacity: 0
      })),
      transition(':enter, :leave', [
        animate(4000)
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

I want to apply the animation in a child component without redefining it in the child component, how can i achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep your animations in a shared file. In that way, it will be really helpful for you to manage it.

You can see this - https://github.com/commutatus/angular-starterpack/tree/master/src/app/shared

In `shared/animations` you will find the animation, and you can then import these animations in your components.

For importing in component -

```
import {fadeIn} from '~app/shared/animations/index';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  animations: [
    fadeIn
  ]
})
```

**Note - Don't forget to import `BrowserAnimationModule` in your `app.module.ts`. Also, export the animations from the `shared/animation/index`**